# What will be the eventual result of the Milky Ways future mergers?

Tags: space-expansion, galaxy-clusters

I am wondering, after the Milky Way merges with Andromeda and other near by dwarf galaxies and globular clusters, will it then merge with galaxies in the Virgo cluster and even Laniakea? And if so will the eventual result be one super giant galaxy or smaller but still large galaxies orbiting each other whilst the rest of the universe has expanded out of sight?

Comment: Perhaps a better fit for Astronomy SE.

Comment: @StephenG Ah yes, I will ask on there, thanks.

Comment: Can You please add a link, if anyone answers there? I'm also curious

Comment: @Krumuvecis thanks for your answer, I added the question to astronomy stack just because I have had contradictory information in the past, some with the same information as your answer and others say cluster's black holes will combine eventually forming mega black holes, I wanted to get  more opinions or a debate on the subject for clarity.

Comment: After too many mergers, the Milky Way will lose focus on its core business, become harder to manage, and start losing market share. Next comes a leveraged buyout, followed by spinning off bits into their own galaxies, or being shut down and tossed into black holes. Such is the life cycle of a galaxy.

Comment: @JonCuster so black holes with no real estate around?

Comment: Real Estate Ingestion Trusts (or REITs) are the new thing, yes.

Comment: (Sorry, too much stay-at-home).

Answer (score 1):

I unfortunately do not have any sources at hand, but if i understand correctly then no - only the galaxies in the Local group will merge and then be separated from everything else. The Local group itself is moving towards The Great Attractor, however expansion of the universe is slightly faster.

I might be wrong as i read it somewhere a few years ago, but hope that this quick answer helps.